# How to define a default shell for emacs

Tags: emacs

My default shell is fish and I don't want to change it. But in Emacs Tramp doesn't work well with fish. So I just want to set bash as default shell for Emacs only. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic; suggest migration to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the documentation for the `shell` function (`C-h f shell RET`):

```
Program used comes from variable `explicit-shell-file-name',
 or (if that is nil) from the ESHELL environment variable,
 or (if that is nil) from `shell-file-name'.
```

So, if you want to use "/bin/bash" as the shell file in emacs buffers, you can either:

- set the variable `explicit-shell-file-name' in your ~/.emacs file:

  `(setq-default explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/bash")`
- set the ESHELL environment variable in your ~/.profile file:

  `export ESHELL=/bin/bash`
- set the variable `shell-file-name' in your ~/.emacs file:

  `(setq-default shell-file-name "/bin/bash")`

Answer (score 2):

The Tramp manual speaks about problems with fish. Maybe you try what's proposed there:

```
Similar fancy prompt settings are known from the fish shell.
Here you must add in ‘~/.config/fish/config.fish’:

     function fish_prompt
       if test $TERM = "dumb"
          echo "\$ "
       else
          …
       end
     end
```